# Using GitLab REST API without Access Tokens

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Can I run script from `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which will be editing wiki pages via GitLab REST API?

I am not sure, because I use old version of GitLab, which doesn't have Access Tokens.

Can I use something else to `PRIVATE-TOKEN`?

Comment: So which version do you use? Probably you are referring to project access tokens which have been introduced in GitLab 13.0? You should be able to use personal access tokens however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Predefined Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) called `CI_JOB_TOKEN` which will contain an access token you can use to authenticate against the API. If you need a token with Admin access, you'll have to use an Admin User's personal access token, which you can store as a secret variable in Project's Settings -> CI/CD Settings -> Variables.